# Mongoose: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` when creating a new model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose to connect to an MongoLab database, I have separated my database model and stuff as a separate module form the rest of my code. I am trying to create an new Model and then save it to the database. unfortunately, it keeps throwing an error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

### This is my database module

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = (function() {
    var database = {};

    database.Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        ObjectID = database.Schema.ObjectID;

    database.Task = new database.Schema({
        task: String, 
    });

    database.Tasks = mongoose.model('Tasks', database.Task);

    return database;
});
```

### Here is the code that is generating the error:

```
var express = require('express');
var database = require('./database');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('../views/index.jade', {title: 'TODO'});
}); 

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // res.render('../views/index.jade', {title: 'TODO', tasks: req.body.name});
    var task = new database.Task(req.body.name);
    task.save(function(err) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log('Task: ' + task + 'successfully saved!');
        } else {
            res.render('../views/index.jade', {title: 'Error', tasks: 'Error: ' + err});
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I think it has to deal with the scope of `database.js` but I am not to sure. How can I fix this problem?

### Here is the full Stacktrace

```
Test
TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports [as handle] (E:\backbone_example\include\router.js:
13:28)
    at next_layer (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:
103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\route
.js:107:5)
    at c (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:195:24)
    at Function.proto.process_params (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:251:12)
    at next (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:19
)
    at next_layer (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:
77:14)
    at next_layer (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:
81:14)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\route
.js:107:5)
    at c (E:\backbone_example\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:195:24)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.save()` is a method on mongoose models, not schemas. Try:

`var task = new database.Tasks(req.body.name);
task.save(...);`

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save

Comment: You could also do: `database.Tasks.create(req.body.name, function(err){..});`

Comment: I have tried this, and it still does not work. I am thinking deeper about the scope of all of this because I can successfully save stuff when I create everything in the node terminal

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `database` before your save? And I assume the error is coming from the line `task.save...`, is that correct?

Comment: That gives me the same thing @Tony :P

Comment: I use a generator and follow their practices. Might want to structure your database module like this one: https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/master/server/api/thing/thing.model.js since it would appear your stacktrace indicates a problem with your `require`.